# Metric entropy of mixed norm spaces with exponent-free bounds

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, approximation-theory, entropy

Suppose $\mathcal{F}\subset L^p([0,1]^d)$ is a subset with the following property: The $L^q$-covering number of $\mathcal{F}$ is independent of $q$, for all $1\le q\le\infty$. An example of $\mathcal{F}$ is the classical H"{o}lder space $\mathcal{C}^{\alpha}$, whose metric entropy scales like $K_{p,q,\alpha}(1/\epsilon)^{d/\alpha}$ in $d$-dimensions.

Now suppose I am given $p_1,\ldots,p_d$ and wish to bound the covering numbers of $\mathcal{F}$ in the mixed $L_{p_1,\ldots,p_d}$ norm. (I am not sure this is standard terminology, so when $d=2$ what I mean is:
$$
\Vert f\Vert_{p_1,p_2}
:= \Big(\int\Big(\int f(x,y)^{p_1}\,dx\Big)^{p_2/p_1}\,dy\Big)^{1/p_2},
$$
with the obvious extension for $d>2$.)

Since the covering number of $\mathcal{F}$ only depend on the exponents $p_j$ through a multiplicative factor, I am hoping it is true that the $L_{p_1,\ldots,p_d}$-covering number is the same as the $L^{p_j}$-covering number (again, up to constants).

Is it known whether this is true or false?